# Match number at the end of the string

Tags: php, regex

Given the following string how can I match the entire number at the end of it?

```
$string = "Conacu P PPL Europe/Bucharest 680979";
```

I have to tell that the lenght of the string is not constant.

My language of choice is PHP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You could use a regex with [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/preg_match), like this :

```
$string = "Conacu P PPL Europe/Bucharest 680979";

$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#(\d+)$#', $string, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

And you'll get :

```
string '680979' (length=6)
```

And here is some information:

- The `#` at the beginning and the end of the regex are the delimiters -- they don't mean anything : they just indicate the beginning and end of the regex ; and you could use whatever character you want (people often use `/` )
- The '$' at the end of the pattern means "end of the string"
- the `()` means you want to capture what is between them

  - with `preg_match`, the array given as third parameter will contain those captured data
  - the first item in that array will be the whole matched string
  - and the next ones will contain each data matched in a set of `()`
- the `\d` means "a number"
- and the `+` means one or more time

So :

- match one or more number
- at the end of the string

For more information, you can take a look at [PCRE Patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) and [`Pattern Syntax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

Comment: Is there any particular advantage to using # around your regex instead of /?  Just for my own curiosity?

Comment: You don’t need the grouping. `$matches[0]` already contains the whole match.

Comment: Not in this case, but in some cases it makes sense, when you want to use /'s in your regex as a character to match. Some people just do this sort of thing out of habit (I usually use an @ sign for instance)

Comment: @Mark : not in this case ; but there would be a difference if the pattern did contain some slashes (like a portion of an URL, for instance) ;; @Psyche : you're welcome ;; @Gumbo : true ; but I prefer having the grouping already in place since the beginning, for the day I'll have to modify the pattern to add more stuff : this way, I won"t have to modify the rest of the code

Answer (score 5):

The following regex should do the trick:

```
/(\d+)$/
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** This answer checks if the very last character in a string is a digit or not. As the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/12258656/1331430 was closed as an exact duplicate of this one, I'll post my answer for it here. For what this question's OP is requesting though, use the accepted answer.

---

Here's my non-regex solution for checking if the last character in a string is a digit:

```
if (ctype_digit(substr($string, -1))) {
    //last character in string is a digit.
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Cadsar)

`substr` passing start=`-1` will return the last character of the string, which then is checked against `ctype_digit` which will return `true` if the character is a digit, or `false` otherwise.

**References:**

1. [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)
2. [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Answer (score 0):

To get the number at the end of a string, without using regex:

```php
function getNumberAtEndOfString(string $string) : ?int 
{
  $result = sscanf(strrev($string), "%d%s");
  if(isset($result[0])) return strrev($result[0]);
  return null;
}
var_dump(getNumberAtEndOfString("Conacu P PPL Europe/Bucharest 680979")); //int(680979)
```