# PHP array doesnt recognise the variable value

Tags: php

Please read the code below and comments to see what I'm trying to do. Its hard to explain in a paragraph.

```
$url_fixx = 'home/sublink/group-view/product/catview1'; 
// What my variable holds. MY GOAL IS: I want to omit group-view, product and catview1 from this so I use the trick below.
```

catview has a random number at the end so I use the code below to find the number at the end and it outputs "catview1" in this case

```
$string = $url_fixx;
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#(catview\d+)$#', $string, $matches)) {
    $catViewCatch = ($matches[1]);
 }
// I got this from http://stackoverflow.com/a/1450969/1567428

$url_fixx = str_replace( array( 'group-view/', 'product', 'catview1' ), '', $url_fixx );
// this outputs what I want.
```

MY QUESTION IS :

```
//When I replace "catview1" with $catViewCatch, the whole str_replace doesnt work. 
$url_fixx = str_replace( array( 'group-view/', 'product', $catViewCatch), '', $url_fixx );
```

Why is that? and what am I doing wrong?

PS: Also my url sometimes changes to something like this.
    $url_fixx = 'home/sublink/group-view/anotuer-sublink/123-article'

How can I tackle all these ?

Comment: What does `$catViewCatch` contain when you capture it using the `preg_match` call? Also, if your URL is always 5 levels like this, why not just `explode` on the `/` character, and slice off the first 2 elements of the array?

Comment: @JonahBishop $catViewCatch contains "catview1" when i capture it using preg_match. I cant use explode because the url can change. Sometimes $url_fixx = 'home/sublink/group-view/anotuer-sublink/123-article';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your examples output the exact same thing. The below code demonstrates this:

```
<?php
$url_fixx = 'home/sublink/group-view/product/catview1';

$string = $url_fixx;
$matches = array();
if (preg_match('#(catview\d+)$#', $string, $matches)) {
    $catViewCatch = ($matches[1]);
}
echo str_replace( array( 'group-view/', 'product', 'catview1' ), '', $url_fixx );
echo '<br />';
echo str_replace( array( 'group-view/', 'product', $catViewCatch), '', $url_fixx );
?>
```

Also, you might consider using [preg_replace](http://php.net/preg_replace) instead as it will accomplish the task with less code:

```
echo preg_replace('#group-view/product/catview[0-9]+#','',$url_fixx);
```

Comment: Thanks. I commented on Jonah's reply saying my url can change. What If if my url changes like this  $url_fixx = 'home/sublink/group-view/anotuer-sublink/123-article'

Comment: How do you want your example URL to look? I'm having trouble understanding the format to give you a good answer.

Comment: All I want to do is remove all the "group-view" "product" and "catview[number]" values from my url. Thats it.

Comment: You might consider using [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) for that but to stick to the one line solution you could use the following: `echo preg_replace('#(group-view/)|(product/)|(catview[0-9]+)#','',$url_fixx);`