# split string in numbers and text but accept text with a single digit inside

Tags: php, regex, string, split, preg-match

Let's say I want to split this string in two variables:

```
$string = "levis 501";
```

I will use

```
preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $num);
preg_match('/\D+/', $string, $text);
```

but then let's say I want to split this one in two

```
$string = "levis 5° 501";
```

as `$text = "levis 5°";` and `$num = "501";`

So my guess is I should add a rule to the `preg_match('/\d+/', $string, $num);` that looks for numbers only at the END of the string and I want it to be between 2 and 3 digits.
But also the $text match now has one number inside...

How would you do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450967/match-number-at-the-end-of-the-string: [`^.*\b(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/cR9rL8/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok but then how do you match "levis 5°" ?

Comment: Group the `.*`; aka `(.*)`.

Comment: [`^(.*?)\s*(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/cR9rL8/2). Bascially the same as fusion3k's. Do you always need to only match 2 parts only? Or can there be more than 2? You can try [`\s*(?=\s*\d+\D*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/cR9rL8/4) with `preg_split`.

Comment: yes I need two parts

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please check, and let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To slit a string in two parts, use any of the following:

```
preg_match('~^(.*?)\s*(\d+)\D*$~s', $s, $matches);
```

This regex matches:

- `^` - the start of the string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing any one or more characters, as few as possible (as `*?` is a "lazy" quantifier) up to...
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace symbols
- `(\d+)` - Group 2 capturing 1 or more digits
- `\D*` - zero or more characters other than digit (it is the opposite shorthand character class to `\d`)
- `$` - end of string.

The `~s` modifier is a DOTALL one forcing the `.` to match any character, even a newline, that it does not match without this modifier.

Or

```
preg_split('~\s*(?=\s*\d+\D*$)~', $s);
```

This `\s*(?=\s*\d+\D*$)` pattern:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces, but only if followed by...
- `(?=\s*\d+\D*$)` - zero or more whitespaces followed with 1+ digits followed with 0+ characters other than digits followed with end of string.

The `(?=...)` construct is a positive lookahead that does not consume characters and just checks if the pattern inside matches and if yes, returns "true", and if not, no match occurs.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/GTxpdD):

```
$s = "levis 5° 501";
preg_match('~^(.*?)\s*(\d+)\D*$~s', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches[1] . ": ". $matches[2]. PHP_EOL);
print_r(preg_split('~\s*(?=\s*\d+\D*$)~', $s, 2));
```

Comment: this one is working for me `"/^(.*?)\\s*(\\d+)$/"` . Could you or anyone point me to a tutorial or something on patterns?

Comment: I do not know your level of regex knowledge :) so that I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean).

Comment: I have added explanations.

Comment: Hello, thanks I checked it, I used this "/^(.*?)\\s*(\\d+)$/" as it seems it's working correctly. Thanks for the clarifications and links, I checked.

Comment: Very glad. Thank you for an interesting question. Keep them coming! :-)