# Checks if a string ends with a number in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, anchor

I want to do a test of variable that starts with a string that I know; and it ends with a number that I don't know, so the test that I did is:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == 'IF-MIB::ifDescr.'."$[0-9]")
        echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
}
```

I tested with this, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You want to get the last character from a string?

Comment: no i am doing a test with a variable that start with a string that i know and it finish by a number that i don't know ex : 

myvar = 'stringthatikonwit'.'numberthatidontknowit'

Comment: I downvoted because: 1. No sample input & desired output 2. Inadequate search/research evidenced by using partial regex syntax and regex question tag but no regex function.  3. Searching SO for questions containing _`php` `regex` check string ends with number_ surely would have yielded heaps of useful pages.  Posting new duplicate questions unvalues SO and answering these questions reinforces lazy behavior.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450967/match-number-at-the-end-of-the-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$str = 'IF-MIB::ifDescr1';

 if(preg_match('/^IF-MIB::ifDescr([0-9]+)$/', $str, $match)){
      echo $match[1];
 }
```

Outputs:

```
 1
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b2fba304bb2da7f687715fb9ae14f0008f9c301)

So putting it all together for your use case:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
   if (preg_match('/^IF-MIB::ifDescr[0-9]+$/', $key)){
       echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
   }
}
```

<s>The `^` at the starts denotes that the string must start with I, and the extra brackets and plus this time state that after the `IF-MIB::ifDescr`, there can be any number of numbers.</s>

Just to explain:

- `^` is Start of string
- `IF-MIB::ifDescr` match literal string
- `[0-9]` character set `0` through `9`, `+` one or more times "greedy"
- `$` end of string

And in the first one

- `(...)` capture group, which is used to return what is matched inside it.

So `$match[1]` is what is captured by the first capture group, `$match[0]` is the full match.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches)`
where the function will return `boolean` and `$matches` an array with the instances found from your pattern.

Pattern `/[0-9]$/` in human is “String ending with a numeric value.”.

```
$word = "asdfñlkas6";
var_dump(preg_match('/[0-9]$/', $word, $matches));
var_dump($matches);
```

Will output:

```
int(1)
array(1) {
  [0]=> string(1) "6"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get last character then [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check if it's numeric

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric(substr($key, -1))) {
        echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, you're simply checking that it ends with the **string** `$[0-9]`.

What you want o do is run a **[`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)** against the string as `/[0-9]$/`. The dollar sign after the numbers denotes that they must come at the end.

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
  if (preg_match("/[0-9]$/", $key) {
    echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
  }
}
```

Note that if you additionally want the other component at the start, it can be achieved with:

```
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
  if (preg_match("/^IF-MIB::ifDescr([0-9]+)$/", $key) {
    echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
  }
}
```

The `^` at the starts denotes that the string must start with `I`, and the extra brackets and plus this time state that after the `IF-MIB::ifDescr`, there can be any number of numbers.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`"$[0-9]"` is certainly a regular expression, but to PHP, it's just another string.

You need to use a function that evaluates a regular expression. [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will do the job for you.

Before this, you should know that `$[0-9]` won't actually match what you intend, since `$` matches the end of a line, or string. Instead, swap it for the end of the capture range like this - `[0-9]$`.

We want to match something like `IF-MIB::ifDescr1<EOL>` not `<EOL>IF-MIB::ifDescr1`.

In order to ensure our string starts with `IF-MIB::ifDescr`, we use the opposite anchor to `$` which is `^` -- matching the beginning of a line or string. Without these anchors, you would match strings like `<whatever>IF-MIB1::ifDescr1<whatever>`.

```
if (preg_match("/^IF-MIB::ifDescr[0-9]$/", $key, $matches)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$str = 'IF-MIB::ifDescr.';
foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
  $checker = trim($str,$value);

  if(is_numeric($checker ))
    echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';

}
```

[Reference for is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

[Reference for trim](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_string_trim)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I might use a regular expression, but for completeness; trim numbers from the end and compare:

```
if(($s = rtrim($key, '0..9')) == 'IF-MIB::ifDescr' && $s != $key)
    echo $key . '=>' . $value . '<br/>';
}
```